# EventLog Auditing AD Get User IP

Tags: windows, active-directory, event-log

Which auditing settings should be enabled in order to see AD logged in user's ip address?

Comment: What do you want to Audit ? People who authentify using AD or connexions to 389 port ?

Comment: People who authentify using AD. (Or I think so. I want to audit people logging in from a computer with their AD username and password.)

Answer (score 0):

On any Domain Server, in the event log, you can find the information you ask for

Here is the extraction of a user login Event "4624" and logout Event "4634" you can make a relation betwen the events by the data named TargetLogonId. The IP adress is in data named IpAdress.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4624</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12544</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-26T11:09:52.930000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>33354</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="512" ThreadID="3244" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>WM2008R2ENT.dom.fr</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-21-314535540-1235592268-145203568-1000</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">WM2008R2ENT2$</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">MOD</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x6ded7f</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonProcessName">Kerberos</Data>
    <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">Kerberos</Data>
    <Data Name="WorkstationName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="LogonGuid">{7B3D7A34-80A9-F1B2-CCF1-7F783ED88C28}</Data>
    <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data>
    <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">192.168.183.101</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">51243</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Here is the extraction of a user logout Event "4634"

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4634</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12545</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-26T11:10:03.070625000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>33355</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="512" ThreadID="3244" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>WM2008R2ENT.dom.fr</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-21-314535540-1235592268-145203568-1000</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">WM2008R2ENT2$</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">MOD</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x6ded7f</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```