# List Disabled Accounts Due To Excess Password Attempts on Redhat Directory Server and Correlate With IP Address

Tags: sql, logging, ldap, redhat, rhel

I'm trying to get a log of disabled user accounts due to excess password attempts and then correlate the attempts and specific accounts with the IP adress they originated from.

I can get a list of disabled user accounts per instructions at [SQL Query for Disabled Active Directory Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324361/sql-query-for-disabled-active-directory-accounts) but am not sure how to correlate those accounts with IP logs.

This is on Redhat Directory Server.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

If your Directory is Active-Directory you can corelate it with the Domain Servers event log. I give an example in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000262/eventlog-auditing-ad-get-user-ip/6137696#6137696), it exist to events : login Event "4624" and logout Event "4634" you can make a relation betwen the events by the data named TargetLogonId. The IP adress is in data named IpAdress. "4740" means that an account was locked.

The problem here is that you need to get all the Domain servers logs.

[Description of security events in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947226/en-us) can help you